# Is there an industry standard for information exchange among financial applications?

Tags: integration, finance

We're developing an accounting and ERP application (something that lots of companies, big and small, use to run their businesses), and I was pondering about the possibility to interconnect two unrelated instances of the application. For example, if company A would write a bill company B, and they both happened to use our application, the bill would get sent automatically to the application instance that the company B is using. Saves time and errors of duplicate data entry.

Of course, bills are just one, the most obvious example. I'm sure there are many more.

Naturally, such a brilliant idea cannot be mine alone so I was wondering what other applications are using for such purposes, and if there are any industry standards out there. Having our application able to connect to other vendor's products with 0 additional work would be awesome.

I came across [OFX](http://www.ofx.net/), but comments here on SO give me the impression that it's more suited to banking industry, and not small scale applications, although it is supposed to be extensible. Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Edifact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDIFACT), as of today still the standard in that field.  There are numerous ready-to-use solutions to interact with Edifact and by extension with EDI based interchange protocols.

However, EDI is not really a lightweight solution...

Comment: We don't really have a lightweight app. XD